# OpenWrt Script (Inifinite Loop) Stops sending data over Serial Port

Tags: linux, shell, arduino, router, openwrt

I have a TP Link Router TL-MR3020 flashed with the latest Attitude Adjustment. It is connected to an Arduino Uno via the usb port (usb cable into the arduino's type b connector). I have the following packages on the router:

kmod-usb-acm (to communicate with the arduino)

kmod-batman-adv

iwinfo

When ever I try to run the below script it will go but after a while (30-300 seconds) it will stop sending data to the arduino (it wont even send the second line sometimes).

I want to have this script start on startup and continue to run while the router is still on without crashing/hanging/stalling (in the processes list in the gui web interface the script says it is still running but there is no output).

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this/ what is causing my problem?

`#!/bin/sh`

`while true
do
 iwinfo wlan0-1 info | grep -w "Signal" >/dev/ttyACM0
 iwinfo wlan0-1 info | grep -w "Tx-Power" >/dev/ttyACM0
 sleep 1
done`

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/830358/4714

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is here for the start-up issue: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts

Maybe you could try putting a sleep 1 after each *iwinfo* call.

I doubt your tx-power and signal strength are going to fluctuate that much, even for real time data, so a sleep 4+ would work just as well.